# How can I convert `A_B_C_DEF` to `ABC_DEF`?

Tags: python, regex

I have strings of this form:

```
A_B_CDEF_GHI
A_B_C_DEF_G_H_I
ABC_D_E_F_GHI
ABCDEFG_H_I
A_B_C
```

I need to convert those to the following:

```
AB_CDEF_GHI
ABC_DEF_GHI
ABC_DEF_GHI
ABCDEFG_HI
ABC
```

So the rules are:

- `(._){2,}` should be converted to `XXX_` if it's not at the end of the string.
- If `(_.){2,}` occurs at the end of a string, it should be converted to `_XXX`.
- If `(_.){2,}.` is the *entire* string, all underscores should be removed.

I've gotten to `(((.)_){2,})`, which does match the first rule, but how can I replace it with the non-underscore characters it found?

> The `python` tag is present because that's where the code is, and I know regex dialects depend on the language.

Comment: How refreshing to read a clear, succinct, unambiguous question!

Comment: Is `'____B_CDEF_GHI'` (4 underscores at the beginning) to become `'B_CDEF_GHI'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot in your example code matches any character including an underscore. You can make the pattern a bit more specific instead.

You can get all of the double A-Z matches out of the way, and capture the single A-Z followed by `_` and A-Z in a group.

Then for the capture group replace the `_` with an empty string.

```
_?[A-Z]{2,}_?|([A-Z](?:_[A-Z](?![A-Z]))+)
```

- `_?[A-Z]{2,}_?` Match 2 or more occurences of A-Z surrounded by optional underscores
- `|` or
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z]` Match a single A-Z
  - `(?:_[A-Z](?![A-Z]))+` Repeat 1+ times `_` and A-Z asserting not A-Z to the right
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KdF8aF/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/dYiPF8)

For example:

```
import re
pattern = r'_?[A-Z]{2,}_?|([A-Z](?:_[A-Z](?![A-Z]))+)'
s = ("A_B_CDEF_GHI\n"
            "A_B_C_DEF_G_H_I\n"
            "ABC_D_E_F_GHI\n"
            "ABCDEFG_H_I\n"
            "A_B_C")

res = re.sub(pattern, lambda x: x.group(1).replace("_", "") if x.group(1) else x.group(), s)
print(res)
```

Output

```
AB_CDEF_GHI
ABC_DEF_GHI
ABC_DEF_GHI
ABCDEFG_HI
ABC
```

---

A bit broader match instead of characters A-Z could be using a negated character class matching any char except a whitespace char or underscore

```
_?[^_\s]{2,}_?|([^_\s](?:_[^_\s](?![^_\s]))+)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked perfectly. Saved so much time trying to figure out how to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without regular expressions:

```py
def convert(s: str) -> str:
    """ https://stackoverflow.com/q/71578300 """

    def _get_combined_parts() -> Iterator[str]:
        """
        yields the ``_``-separated parts of ``s``
        where subsequent single-character parts have been combined
        """
        combined_part = ""
        for part in s.split("_"):
            if len(part) <= 1:
                combined_part += part
            else:
                if combined_part:
                    yield combined_part
                yield part
                combined_part = ""
        if combined_part:
            yield combined_part

    return "_".join(_get_combined_parts())
```

Comment: A few measurements on my system suggest that my solution is twice as fast as the one of https://stackoverflow.com/a/71578365/13134095. 